# Comm command failing when inpput given through variable

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to find common names in a file and file name is generated dynamically. But when I try to give the filename using the $ size its not getting replaced tried echo and then eval but get an error as an unexpected token (

The code is as below

```
hive -e "use $1;show tables;">$1.txt
eval $(echo "comm -12 <(sort -u hub_table_list) <(sort -u $1.txt) >result.txt")
```

The hive command runs succesfully file is created with the parameter name.
It contains the table names.
All Help appreciated.

Comment: is `sout` actually in your code or typo while posting here?

Comment: also consider using `grep -Fxf file1 file2` to get common lines between two files

Comment: Thanks this worked